# Why is quickly ignoring the setup.py file in my project directory?

Tags: software-center, application-development, deb, quickly, glade

Whenever I try to package my application with quickly, the following error pops up in my terminal:

[image: Error]

And the package is in the directory. Whoop de doo.

[image: .deb]

Then, when I go to open the .deb file in Ubuntu Software Center to install it:

[image: UNKNOWN]

The application can install fine but the description is messed up.
What's happening here? I do have a 64-bit version of Ubuntu, but does that make a difference? I know that the setup.py file is fine:

[image: setup.py]
[image: dir]

So whats going on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quickly is building the package just fine, it's simply that you haven't specified the package descriptions (the short one and the long one) for your app.

Try the following:

- Uncomment the `description` and `long_description` lines in `setup.py`
- Add the description for your app
- Re-run the `quickly package` command

That should sort it out.

Comment: oh. Im an idiot. I thought that the "#" were part of html.